# start and stop data saving on .txt file using button on c#

Tags: c#, user-interface, filestream

I have a sensor that connected to pc and data comes continuously like this picture:[image: GUI]

I want to add two start and stop button and save data from start button pressed time and stop saving data when pressed stop button.

I write this code:

```
richTextBox1.AppendText(textBox1.Text + "\n");
System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(@"C:\Users\Mohammad_Taghi\Desktop\a.txt",richTextBox1.Lines);
```

but this code save whole of data in .txt file and is not controllable.

this is that part of code on richtextbox2:

```
public void detectFingers(Leap.Frame frame)

        {
            foreach(Finger finger in frame.Fingers)
            {
                richTextBox2.AppendText("Finger ID: " + finger.Id + Environment.NewLine +
                                        "Finger Type: " + finger.Type + Environment.NewLine +
                                        "Finger Length:" + finger.Length + Environment.NewLine +
                                        "Finger width:" + finger.Width + Environment.NewLine);

                foreach (Bone.BoneType boneType in (Bone.BoneType[])Enum.GetValues(typeof(Bone.BoneType)))
                {
                    Bone bone = finger.Bone(boneType);
                richTextBox3.AppendText("Bone Type: " + bone.Type +Environment.NewLine +
                                        "Bone Length: " +bone.Length  +Environment.NewLine+
                                        "Bone Width : " + bone.Width +Environment.NewLine +
                                        "Previous Joint : "+bone.PrevJoint + Environment.NewLine+
                                        "Next Joint :" + bone.NextJoint + Environment.NewLine+
                                        "Direction : " + bone.Direction + Environment.NewLine+;


                }

            }


        }
```

Comment: How data is being displayed in textBox1? There should be an event or something similar that receives data from your sensors. Please post that part of code.

Answer (score 0):

As data comes in continuously you need to save from when the data should be stored uptil when. Printing the textBox1.Text will, of course, print everything.

You need to set a variable to store the information after the "Start" button is pressed until the "Stop" button is pressed. Here is some code:

```
private bool isLogging = false;
        private string myLog = "";

        //This is where the input from the sensor arrives
        private void myInput(string s)
        {
            textBox1.Text += s + "\n";
            if (isLogging)
                myLog += s + "\n";
        }
        private void buttonOnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Clear log string
            myLog = "";
            //Start logging
            isLogging = true;
        }

        private void buttonOnStop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Stop logging
            isLogging = false;
            //Pring only the logged messages
            System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(@"C:\Users\Mohammad_Taghi\Desktop\a.txt", myLog);
        }
```

Comment: i have three richTextBox and three textbox.

Comment: Doesn't change the fact, it still works the same. In "myInput" (or your information is received) set the string or create a string for each of these values (or create a list).